# App submission on store : Save button is not working

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a windows phone app ready to be submitted in app store. I uploaded all the files necessary & added all the information required according to msdn guide. The problem is, "Save" button in "Upload & describe your xap" section is not working. It doesn't show me any error or anything, it simple doesn't works. What could be the problem? Am I missing something or it is a silverlight or any other problem? Please share your opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only Internet Explorer 10 for the WP8 dashboard.